# best resources to start programming eclipse plug-ins

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

Either books (free or not), online tutorials, articles, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wiki: [Eclipse Plug-in Development FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Plug-in_Development_FAQ) is a good start.

But you need to look at [**Osgi**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/OSGi) which manages the lifecycle of the plugins you will develop.
For that, the free book "[Osgi in practice](http://neilbartlett.name/blog/osgibook/)" is excellent.

Comment: Funny. This is the first time I see that the official site of something points to wikipedia instead of providing itself the explanations.

Comment: @x-x: True, but Osgi in itself is not "made" by Eclipse, so to avoid another collection of pointers on that external topic... they refer to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many useful examples and snippets in the eclipse cvs:

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/

regards
Karl

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is the best book about the eclipse plug-in development.

[http://www.qualityeclipse.com](http://www.qualityeclipse.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I used ["The Java Developer's Guide to Eclipse"](http://www.jdg2e.com/)

Answer (score 0):

*SWT: The Standard Widget Toolkit* is a really good book.

I wish I've had read that book when I started out writing Eclipse plug-ins, it would have saved me a lot of time. The book gives you a deep understanding of SWT, which I believe is necessary if you're going to write anything professionally. The book explains all those little details you otherwise will have to spend hours searching the net for; how do layout managers really work, what is the event loop?

When it comes to integrating with the Eclipse workbench; using extensions points, editors, views, menus, commands/handlers/viewers, etc. I think you can pick it up by playing around with some of the plug-in development wizards that comes with Eclipse. The books I've read so far, about JFace and plug-in development in general, haven't really been helpful.

Also, don't forget to look at the Eclipse source code. It will give you a lot of ideas how to do things. Good luck!